# Regular expression to remove multiple segments in file names

Tags: regex, file-rename, batch-rename

I have several files to rename. I will rename them using a batch renamer software. It can remove patterns using regular expression. Here are two file name examples:

- `13 (a 3f kd) kjhucj 1 _ m (52 min) - jrhkfq 324`
- `647 fjk3 d [63h hh] _ (jhgbh) abim (238 min)`

I want to remove all characters after `_\s` but keep the `\(\d+\smin\)` part. I want them to be renamed to:

- `13 (a 3f kd) kjhucj 1 (52 min)`
- `647 fjk3 d [63h hh] (238 min)`

I tried `_\s.*[^(\(\d+\smin\))]` but got weird results. I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: Does your regex tool have the ability to use capture groups in the replacement?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have no idea. The software name is advanced renamer. What I know is that it can apply multiple patterns separately for the same batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really trying to do is remove everything between `_\s` and `(`, as well as everything after `)`. Alternatively, you want to keep everything up to `_\s`, and between `(` and `)`. You should aim to define the delimiters of your capture groups rather than the contents most of the time:

```
(.+?)_\s.*(\(\d+ min\)).*
```

In this case, instead of removing, keep the contents of capture groups 1 and 2 only. Many tools will allow you to say something like `\1\2` in the replacement pattern.

If your tool removes an entire match and you insist on doing it like that, you will have to use a two pass approach, since you have two disconnected regions to remove. This would require a tool that supports lookahead and lookbehind, as most of them do.

The first pass would use

```
_\s.*(?=\(\d+ min\))
```

The second pass would remove

```
(?<=\(\d+ min\)).*
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I had to use another software as previous one does not support lookbehind. The last two expressions have typo, need one more `)`.

Comment: @ripu. There were actually extra opening braces. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are special characters in regular expressions: when you put a group of characters between a `[` and a `]` they are interpreted as matching any one character in the collection. However, here you seem to want to match a real `[` character. You can make the `[` not *special* by putting a backslash in front of it, so try replacing the `[` in your regular expressions with a `\[` and see whether that helps.